# ECC Key Wrapping with Conscrypt on Android

Tags: java, android, cryptography

I'm using Conscrypt on Android (BTW, I have set minSdkVersion to 23). I have written some code to wrap and unwrap an ECC Public Key. An AES Key is used for this wrap/unwrap:

```
private void testWrapFunctions(Key eccKey) {

    try {
        byte[] randomAesKey = generateSecureRandomBytes(AES_KEY_SIZE/8);
        SecretKeySpec aesKey = generateAESKey(randomAesKey);

        Cipher myCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");

        myCipher.init(Cipher.WRAP_MODE, aesKey);
        byte[] wrappedData = myCipher.wrap(eccKey);

        myCipher.init(Cipher.UNWRAP_MODE, aesKey);
        Key unWrappedKey = myCipher.unwrap(wrappedData, "AES/GCM/NoPadding", Cipher.PUBLIC_KEY);

    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When I run this code, I've got the following exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: error:0f00007b:elliptic curve routines:OPENSSL_internal:UNKNOWN_GROUP
```

Here is the backtrace:

```
System.err:     at org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.EVP_marshal_public_key(Native Method)
System.err:     at org.conscrypt.OpenSSLECPublicKey.getEncoded(OpenSSLECPublicKey.java:91)
System.err:     at org.conscrypt.OpenSSLCipher.engineWrap(OpenSSLCipher.java:404)
System.err:     at javax.crypto.Cipher.wrap(Cipher.java:1677)
System.err:     at com.st.st25dvcryptodemo.MyApplication.testWrapFunctions(MyApplication.java:187)
```

Do you know what I could have done wrong?
Thanks

Comment: If I wrap a RSA public key then the wrap() and unwrap() operations work. What could be wrong when wrapping an ECC Public Key?

Comment: I'm using the ECC key "secp256k1". This curve is not supported natively by Conscrypt but I have defined it as done here: https://github.com/google/conscrypt/blob/master/openjdk-integ-tests/src/test/java/org/conscrypt/java/security/SignatureTest.java (Line 3062)
I have seen a BoringSSL thread (https://github.com/netty/netty-tcnative/issues/340 ) where someone has the same "OPENSSL_internal:UNKNOWN_GROUP" error. The bug has been closed because the "secp256k1" curve is not supported by BoringSSL.
Does it mean that it is not possible to wrap a curve (like "secp256k1") not supported by Conscrypt?

Comment: I have replaced the curve "secp256k1" by "prime256v1" and the wrap and unwrap operations are then working fine.